# Facebook API metric for result/conversions

Tags: facebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stitch

I've got Facebook campaigns set up to catch *All URL Traffic where URL contains*, which is my custom conversion. It generates a *Custom Conversions ID* and a *Data Source Pixel ID*. Based on those I can see "results" generated in the admin panel under literally a *Results* section.

Now I've got this connected to Snowflake using Stitch, and it pulls a ton of json-like elements, but I can't seem to match any of those to the Result section. Where am I supposed to look? Or am I missing something with the integration? Json-like element sample:

```
[{
    "1d_click": 1,
    "1d_view": 3,
    "28d_click": 2,
    "28d_view": 4,
    "7d_click": 1,
    "7d_view": 4,
    "action_destination": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "action_target_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "action_type": "lead",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "1d_click": 1,
    "1d_view": 4,
    "28d_click": 2,
    "28d_view": 5,
    "7d_click": 1,
    "7d_view": 5,
    "action_destination": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "action_target_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion",
    "value": 5
}]
```

To give you even more context, the spec above comes from an ADS_INSIGHTS table -> UNIQUE_ACTIONS column, while there are also many other tables (please see an image below), and so to filter it down to the above json selection, I am joining ADS_INSIGHTS and ADS on Ads IDs, which lets me filter the data by an ad name and check active ads only.

So my question is: where in all of this do I find equivalent of the Results? Which conversions should I be looking at? I read the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/tracking-specs), but still not getting it and my overall conversions do not match up between the native Fb dashboard interface and what I see in Snowflake. I.e. I know that I need to see 9 conversions in the Snowflake for a given campaign name, but different combinations do not render these 9 when I play with the received data. Please share thoughts.

[image: Inside Snowflake]

UPD: the best I could get so far is by [reading this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/) and looking at `offsite_conversion.custom.<custom_conv_id>` in table ADS_INSIGHTS, column ACTIONS.